# How to extract features from a vector layer?

Tags: grass-gis, vector

I have a vector file containing the river lines of an area. I want to extract a specific water line from the vector. I used:
`v.db.select` but it only displayed:

```
   cat|F_CODE_DES|HYC_DESCRI|NAM|ISO|NAME_0
    1|River/Stream|Perennial/Permanent|UNK|PHL|Philippines
    2|River/Stream|Perennial/Permanent|UNK|PHL|Philippines
    3|River/Stream|Perennial/Permanent|UNK|PHL|Philippines
...
```

then i used `v.extract` to select a specific area and it displayed this error:

```
v.extract input=vector_waterLines@PERMANENT output=vector_1 where=1             
DBMI-DBF driver error:
ERROR: Unable select records from table <vector_waterLines>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` switch should be an SQL statement.  From the GRASS manual:

> where=sql_query
>       WHERE conditions of SQL statement without 'where' keyword
>       Example: income < 1000 and inhab >= 10000

For example, if you want to extract only perennial streams:

`v.extract input=vector_waterLines@PERMANENT output=vector_1 where="HYC_DESCRI = 'Perennial/Permanent'"`

Comment: I want to extract only a specific line, but I'm not sure what is the label of that line. I tried `v.extract input=vector_waterLines@PERMANENT output=vector_2 where="cat = '3'"` but it displayed: `DBMI-DBF driver error:
ERROR: Unable select records from table <vector_waterLines>`

Comment: the names in the database of my vector file have several "UNK" (unknown) values. That is why I cannot query well. Is there a site wherein I can download another vector file for the river lines? I got mine from (http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) or is it possible for me to extract a specific river line since I can pinpoint it in the GIS Map display?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can extract specific vector lines using the `cat` values.  There must be something wrong with your dbf tables.

Comment: Regarding river lines, I haven't seen diva-gis' data but you can get very good river lines on selected areas of the Philippines in Openstreetmap.

Comment: I searched for the Openstreetmap and it was just viewable and cannot be downloaded in order to be opened in GRASS as a vector

Comment: @teamAngat, try these links for a shapefile download:  http://downloads.cloudmade.com/ http://download.geofabrik.de/